Intellij coverage considers ignored files
I have a test suite configured and I want to run it with coverage (using jacoco)
I have these exclusions set up for jacoco doesn't consider generated files:
    jacocoExclusions = ['**/*_*AutoProvide*/**', "**/*_Provide*/**", "**/*_*Factory*/**",                             "**/*_MembersInjector.class", "**/*Dagger*", "**/AutoValue_*", "**/AutoOneOf_*"]
    ignoreProtoPckgCoverage = true

I run the test suite with coverage through intellij which is set to build and run using gradle, as well as run tests using gradle.
The coverage option in intellij has an annotation exclusion for the @Generated annotation of several types - javax.annotation.Generated and javax.annotation.processing.Generated
The code coverage shows generated classes in grey but their missing coverage is still taken into consideration (see image)
intellij coverage with greyed out generated classes
